# Vanilla Js and AWS Cognito (AWS Amplify) - Is it safe?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, security, authentication, amazon-cognito

I´m working on a pure js (Vanilla JS) project and i need to create an auth method.

I´d like to know if it is safe to let some AWS Cognito informations key on a javascript (.js) file.

This kind of information:

- identityPoolId - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
- userPoolId - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
- userPoolWebClientId - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID

Could my AWS Cognito user pool be hacked or something like that if ipm showing these informations ?

I´m very concerned about security using Vanilla JS, but it is a premisse on this project.

Thanks

Comment: If you have security concerns and are working on a project where the consequences of a security breach could be catastrophic then **hire a certified security professional to advise**.

Answer (score 0):

If done correctly, using the Amazon Cognito API is secure, and much more so than building something yourself. Also accessing the Cognito API using Vanilla JS is just as safe and secure as combining it with a JavaScript frameworks like React, Amplify, or Vue.js.

In fact, it doesn't make a difference if you use Vanilla JS or any framework, as they all run in the user's browser and all the information needed to access the Amazon Cognito API needs to be available on the client side.

Having that said: As @tadman pointed out in the comments, even though the AWS services and APIs are secure, if you are working with sensitive data, you should always consult a security specialist to make sure that you haven't missed or misconfigured anything.